# What is the best design for table of parameters?

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm designing an Access database that contains many variable parameters used in equations.

For example, the parameter table contains: fuel cost, working Hours per day(8 or 10), currency exchange rate, applied discount, Project No., ...etc.
All these information are unique i.e. a table of 1 record.

Such table is not linked with any other table because there is no relation except a parameter is a part of an equation in a query.
Currently I'm using Dlookup to call any of these parameter in a query:

```
DLookUp("[FuelCost]","ParametersT")
```

The query is normally running but the linked report with that query is taking time (sometimes 30 seconds) to run & also during scrolling (refreshing the page).

Such report also contains some calculations and 3 levels of grouping.

Is there a proper way to design the parameter table better than what I'm doing?

Comment: If this table has only record and will always be only one record, it can be included in any query without a JOIN clause and the result is a Cartesian relationship and the ParametersT record will associate with every record of the data table. The query will not be editable so this won't be useful for a form. But try it for the report. If there is only one record, how can HoursPerDay be 8 or 10?

Comment: A field for each parameter limits you to 255 parameters. What if you change a parameter value? Do you want past records to be calculated with the new value? If not, should save parameter value with the record.

Comment: @June7  The parameters are about 50 Nos., its historical values are not required because it will be assigned to a specific project (1 access DB for each project)

Comment: @June7 for your first comment, I don't understand what is the Cartesian relationship. 8 or 10 hrs are working hrs per day

Comment: Google Cartesian relationship. I already described what happens when you include ParametersT in query. The effect is called Cartesian relationship. Do the query and see what happens. So a project will have either 8 or 10 as the HoursPerDay parameter?.

Comment: @June7 I tried with my query but I got the following Message :"The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL statement. (Error 3258)"  So, I converted my select query to create table Query & used the out table with my parameters query in a new query and it's OK now..Thank you